# ¿Cómo puedo escribir en un bloc de notas?

Tags: c#, txt

He conseguido que se escriba en el bloc pero cuando ejecuto otra vez se sobre escribe todo en el bloc de notas, necesitaría que se pusiera abajo del anterior. Gracias de antemano.

Este es mi código:

```
string path = @".\agenda.txt";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    // Create a file to write to.
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("-----");
        sw.WriteLine(nom);
        sw.WriteLine(cognom);
        sw.WriteLine(dni);
        sw.WriteLine(telefon);
        sw.WriteLine(correu);
        sw.WriteLine("-----");
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee el siguiente artículo: [He pensado mejor sobre mi pregunta ¿puedo borrarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question). La vandalización o la eliminación excesiva de publicaciones útiles pueden desencadenar una alerta dentro del sistema y una acción inmediata del equipo de moderación. Sé respetuoso con los esfuerzos de otros: evita invalidar su trabajo o crear una molestia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo más simple escribiendo todas las filas de una sola vez usando el

[File.AppendAllLines](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netframework-4.8)()

entonces sería:

```
string path = @".\agenda.txt";

List<string> lineas = new List<string>();

lineas.Add("-----");
lineas.Add(nom);
lineas.Add(cognom);
lineas.Add(dni);
lineas.Add(telefon);
lineas.Add(correu);
lineas.Add("-----");

File.AppendAllLines(path, lineas);
```

No necesitas validar si el archivo existe porque el `AppendAllLines()` lo creará directamente y, si existe, agregará el nuevo contenido al existente.

Answer (score 2):

Deberias agregar un else después del if (es decir que el archivo existe) y leer el contenido de tu txt, después agregar el string que quieras y cerrarlo.

```
else {
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(rutaArchivo, false);
    sw.Write("Agrego esta linea");
    sw.Close();
}
```

1. Se abre el archivo creando un **StreamWriter** pasándole la ruta,
   como segundo parámetro le indicamos si queremos añadir texto al
   archivo cuando escribamos, o sobrescribirlo (true para sobreescribir, false para no).
2. Escribimos el contenido en el archivo con **Write**.
3. Cerramos el archivo con **Close()** para que no quede bloqueado.

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Hola gracias por la ayuda pero no era esto lo que pedia perdon me explico mal lo que yo quiero es cuando un usuario ponga su nombre dni y todo se guarde y cuando el siguiente lo ponga se guarde tambien lo que me ocurre es que el primero lo  guarda y el siguiente que quiere guardar sobre escribe al primero gracias otra vez

Comment: Para eso necesitaría ver el código completo, desde la carga de datos. Seguramente tenes algún problema con el ciclo que recorre tus datos y realiza el grabado del txt, porque si el archivo existe jamás va a entrar en ese if que mostraste.