# Mostrar toda la informacion de un usuario c#

Tags: c#

Me gustaria saber como se puede buscar en un archivo .txt

ejemplo si quiero buscar un nombre que sea "Pedro"

no se si me explico 
muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: buscas pero para hacer que ? digo, solo buscar indicando si existe o buscas y recuperar algun otro dato

Comment: Pues tengo un bloc de notas donde tengo el nombre apellido y todo de un usuario ahora me gustaria saber el codigo para cuando pulse buscar y ponga el nombre me aparezca en pantalla toda la informacion del usuario que se llame igual que estoy buscando

Comment: Tu archivo esta organizado con json o xml?

Comment: con txt lo tengo todo

Comment: Podes colocar parte del texto de tu archivo aqui?

Comment: Hola puedes darnos un ejemplo del Txt? Para lograr esos deberías de tener un separador entre datos es decir pongo un ejemplo: nombre|edad|dirección|teléfono

Comment: string path = @".\agenda.txt";
                    List<string> lineas = new List<string>();

                    lineas.Add("-----");
                    lineas.Add(nom);
                    lineas.Add(cognom);
                    lineas.Add(dni);
                    lineas.Add(telefon);
                    lineas.Add(correu);
                    lineas.Add("-----");

                    File.AppendAllLines(path, lineas);

Comment: tengo esto y es donde el usuario introduze sus nombres y eso

Comment: pero por ejemplo si un usuario se pone de nombre Pedro me gustaria saber como buscar los usuariios de que llamen Pedro y saber todo lo que tiene

Comment: saber el numero apellido telefono de todos los pedros de txt

Comment: te aconsejaría que para eso usaras json para formatear una persona, después de eso sera mas fácil buscar una persona y todos sus datos y sera intuitivo de leer el archivo si lo abres con notepad. Te lo coloco como respuesta al ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Partamos que los datos no se organizan como lo planteas en la pregunta previa

[Como puedo escribir en un bloc de notas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330951/como-puedo-escribir-en-un-bloc-de-notas)

Sino que cada linea es un registro y cada dato debe separarse por algun caracter, por lo genera un punto y coma

Entonces guardar usarias

```
string path = @".\agenda.txt";

List<string> lineas = new List<string>();

string dato = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4}", nom, cognom, dni, telefon, correu)
lineas.Add(dato);

File.AppendAllLines(path, lineas);
```

Entonces si podrias recuperar y mostrar la informacion de la persona recuperando la linea de informacion que le corresponde usando algo como esto

```
string path = @".\agenda.txt";

Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre:");
string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

string[] lineas = File.ReadAllLines(path);

//se realiza la busqueda linea a linea
string dato = "";
foreach(string linea in lineas)
{
    if(linea.Contains(nombre))
    {
        dato = linea;
        break;
    }
}

//si se encontro alguna linea coincidente
if(dato != "")
{
    string partes = dato.Split(';');

    Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}", dato[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("codigo: {0}", dato[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("dmi: {0}", dato[2]);
    //resto datos
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void EscribirArchivo()
        {
            List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();
            Persona persona = new Persona();
            string path = @".\agenda.txt";

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre:");
        persona.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el Apellido:");
        persona.Apellido = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la Edad:");
        persona.Edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        personas.Add(persona);

        //se serializa el objeto
        string dato = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personas);
        //Se graba el objeto
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        streamWriter.WriteLine(dato);

        streamWriter.Close();
    }
    private static void ObtenerPersona(string nombre)
    {
        string path = @".\agenda.txt";
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path);

        var json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var dess = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Persona>>(json);
        //deserializas el objeto como un listado y podes recorrerlo con intelisense y trabajar con objeto para seguir adelante.
        foreach (var persona in dess)
        {
            if (persona.Nombre.Equals(nombre))
                Console.WriteLine(persona.ToString());
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No se encontro el registro");
        }
        streamReader.Close();
    }
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EscribirArchivo();

        Console.WriteLine("Escriba el nombre para buscar");
        string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

        ObtenerPersona(nombre);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 public class Persona
        {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Nombre: {Nombre}  | Apellido: {Apellido} | Edad: {Edad}";
        }
    }
```